# Como especificar uma cor em HEXA no MSPaint?

Tags: html, css, background-color

Boa tarde,

É possível especificar uma cor em HEXA no MSPaint? Como faço?

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

O MS PAINT só aceitar RGB, você terá que converter de RGB para HEXA.

Comment: Muito obrigado!